# "Internal id" generation in Postgres (id that is only unique together with another column)

Tags: c#, postgresql, indexing

I have a database structure with schools and courses.

The navigation in the web UI is done with ids, so something like: `/school/1/course/5`.

Right now the id for course is the globally unique id for course.
So course 1 and 3 might belong to school 1, but course 2 belongs to school 2:

```
/school/1/course/1
/school/1/course/3
/school/5/course/2
```

This means that even though school 1 has two courses, the following URL is incorrect, since the course with global id 2 belongs to school 5:

`/school/1/course/2`

I would like to start using some internal ids, where instead of looking up courses by globally unique id, I look them up by both school id and internal id for the course.

So the course table would look like this for the example:

```
| id | school_id | internal_id |
| 1    1           1           |
| 2    5           1           |
| 3    1           2           |
```

When creating my internal ids, what is the best way to increment the id? Is there some way I can do this in the database, or must I find out how many courses there are for a school and use count + 1 for the next internal id?

I'm using a Postgres database and C#.

Comment: What is your plan for deleting a course? Reassign new IDs to all courses with higher IDs (for the same school)? I would advise against that. Try to separate the two functions "identifying" and "numbering/ordering".

Comment: @SebDieBln The plan is to soft delete them in the database. And then when browsing the school the soft deleted courses will not be shown as links, but if accessed directly by URL it will show some data and clearly also say that it's deleted.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a classic Many:Many association between School:Course; a school offers many courses and a course is offered by many schools. The classic solution is to introduce a resolution table which contains the key of both, and if needed attributes for the combination. So something similar too:

```
create table courses ( course_id   integer generated always as identity primary key
                     , name        text    not null unique
                     , description text
                     -- other attributes related to a course and nothing else 
                     ) ;

create table schools ( school_id    integer generated always as identity primary key
                     , name         text    not null unique
                     , location     text
                     , latitude     double precision    -- perhaps 
                     , langitued    double precision    -- perhaps 
                     -- other attributes related to a school and nothing else 
                     ) ; 
                    
create table class_catalog( school_id  integer not null references schools(school_id) 
                          , course_id  integer not null references courses(course_id) 
                          , start_date date         -- perhaps         
                          , end_date   date         -- perhaps 
                          , semester   integer      -- perhaps 
                          -- other attributes related to a combination of school and course 
                          , constraint  class_catalog_pk
                                        primary key (school_id,  course_id)
                          ) ;
```

This eliminates the need for your `internal_id` and your `globally unique id` as you need only the class)id and the course_id. It does not however preclude a the catalog from having its own id. You might want it if you plan to link other entities to it, say student_classes. Just make sure the combination of school_id and course_id id unique (or perhaps within year and semester. I'll leave that definition to you).

```
-- alternate with the insection (association tale) having its own PK 
create table class_catalog_alt( internal_id integer generated always as identity primary key
                              , school_id   integer not null references schools(school_id) 
                              , course_id   integer not null references courses(course_id) 
                              , start_date  date         -- perhaps         
                              , end_date    date         -- perhaps 
                              , semester    integer      -- perhaps 
                              -- other attributes related to the combination of school and course 
                              , constraint  class_catalog_bk
                                            unique (school_id,  course_id)
                              ) ;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but you have misunderstood. A course is not offered by many schools in this case, it's unique to the school. So it's a one-to-many relationship. My wish to have an "internal id" is only due to the fact of how the URLs look, where I would like the course id's to be sequential for a school when browsing.